# How to exit with Ctrl+D like bash with execl?

Tags: c, linux, bash, exec

I'm doing :

`execl("/bin/bash", "/bin/bash", NULL);`

When I do a Ctrl+D, it directly exit. How can I do the same as bash and write `exit` before exiting ?

Do I have to add a flag or something to `execl`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I compile `execl(...)`, it prints exit on <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> just fine

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    execl("/bin/bash", "/bin/bash", 0);
    return 0;
}
```

maybe, you do a `fork()` or detach from the terminal or do something else, which lets bash assume it is non-interactive.

<kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> is usually interpreted by the terminal. If you want to do this yourself, you must reset `VEOF` in the `termios` structure see [`c_cc`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/termios.3.html) for details.

This is a simplified example for handling <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> yourself. It still reads a whole line before processing anything, but you get the idea

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char buf[100];
    int fd;
    struct termios tio;
    fd = open("/dev/tty", O_RDWR);
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("open tty");
        exit(1);
    }

    memset(&tio, 0, sizeof(tio));
    tcgetattr(fd, &tio);
    tio.c_cc[VEOF] = 0;
    tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH);
    tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &tio);

    while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin)) {
        if (buf[0] == 4) {
            printf("Got Ctrl-D\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This program reads a line from the terminal, until it receives a line starting with `Ctrl-D`.

For more examples, see the [Serial Programming HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Serial-Programming-HOWTO/x115.html).

Comment: Indeed, I'm doing a fork. And termcaps to undo the ECHO. I'd like to catch somehow the Ctrl+D. I'm doing an `exelc` in the son, and I read on it in the father. How can I catch the Ctrl+D this way?

Comment: I've already tried something like : `t.c_cc[VEOF] = "exit";`, but it takes a char.

Comment: @Elfayer You must first prevent the terminal from interpreting `Ctrl-D`. Then read from the terminal and act on receiving `Ctrl-D`.

Comment: Thanks, and I've found this : http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/catch-signals-sample-c-code/